# Is "scarcely" an intensifier?

Tags: adverbs

> That was the country he liked best, over there; those sandhills dwindling away into darkness. One could walk all day without meeting a soul. There was not a house **scarcely**, not a single village for miles on end.
>   (Virginia Woolf, To the Lighthouse)

Is *scarcely* an intensifier in the sentence, meaning "at all"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usage is odd; ordinarily we say *there was scarcely a house*, meaning "even one house was rare". *Not ... scarcely* is in effect an almost-double negative. *OED 1* records this use as a "pleonastic negative", but not later than the 18th century.

Woolf slips here, but it's pretty clear what she means. I think you read it correctly as an intensifier, but the meaning is not "there were no houses at all" but "there were *almost* no houses at all".

Comment: Not so much a slip as an accent; the quote's from within Mr. Ramsay's thoughts